# Determine buffer size required for RegQueryValueEx in C

Tags: c, windows, registry

Is there a concrete way to determine the exact buffer size required for a `REG_`BINARY value for `RegQueryValueEx` in C? If possible, please provide code demonstrating method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the winAPI double-call dance, which applies to numerous win APIs besides the `Reg` functions: call [`RegQueryValueEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724911%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) once, passing NULL as `lpData`, and a pointer to `lpcpData`, args 5 and 6. The function will return `ERROR_SUCCESS` and fill `lpcpData` with the required buffer size. Call again with a buffer of that size.

You can also begin with passing a buffer, and if it's too small the function will return `ERROR_MORE_DATA` and fill `lpcpData` with the required buffer size.

Consider the following general pseudo-code for a winapi loop which employs the second approach:

```
// alloc space for buffer, i.e. buffer is non-NULL

do
{
    winret = SomeWinApi(...args..., buffer, &bufferSize, ...more args...);
    if (winret != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        if (winret == ERROR_MORE_DATA)
            // alloc more space
        else
        {
            // more error handling
            break;
        }
    }
    else bufferIncomplete = FALSE;

} while (bufferIncomplete);
```

This also handles cases where the buffer might change size between calls, i.e. a shared buffer or a registry key that's being updated.

Comment: Note that if the data might be changing while you're reading it, you need to do this in a loop, since the necessary buffer size might increase.